# Footer animates up when you reach bottom of screen, but fails to animate down when you scroll back up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a footer that animates up when the user scrolls to the very bottom of the page. Right now it is currently staying in the post-animation state after animation completes. However, I'm trying to get it to animate back down once the user scrolls back up the page a little bit.

Here's my code so far. This correctly animates the footer up, but not back down:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var i;
  i = 0;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()) {
    i = 1;
    $("footer").animate({
      marginBottom: "-22px"
    }, 500);
  }
  else if (i > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() <= $(document).height() * 0.9) {
    $("footer").animate({
      marginBottom: "-156px"
    }, 500);
    i = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle. The CSS styling for the footer is also important in this case. How is it `position`ed? What is the `<html>` or `<body>` height? This and more needs to be addressed for a more complete analysis.

Comment: Try making `i` a global variable (also, consider another name for the variable). Don't set `i = 0` as well. Your `else if` logic won't hit. I'll throw a fiddle together in a sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're resetting your "flag" variable, `i` on every scroll.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating a workaround (and what I mentioned in the comments): http://jsfiddle.net/px8y9/

```
var isShowing = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()) {
        alert("Show Footer");
        isShowing = true;
    } else if (isShowing === true && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() <= $(document).height() * 0.9) {
        alert("Hide Footer");
        isShowing = false;
    }
});
```