# footer animate up when scrolling and touch bottom and animate down when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a question that once asked in a different variation, 
and i tried to use the code, but it doesn't work for me.
I want my footer to animate up when scrolling just a bit before reaching the bottom, and closing while scrolling up.
like in this site - you will see if you scroll all the way down.
http://www.pronto.co.il

this is my code:

css:

```
body, html { height: 1000px; }
```

html:

```
<button id="buttonTest">try me</button>
<div id="footer" style="display: none;"><img src="pics/try_me_1.png" ></div>
```

I'm trying to leave the jquery code but I don't understand exactly how it works here yet. 
so this is the link to the answer - i took it and use animate() instead the alert.
[Footer animates up when you reach bottom of screen, but fails to animate down when you scroll back up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704846/footer-animates-up-when-you-reach-bottom-of-screen-but-fails-to-animate-down-wh)

will help me a lot. thank u so very much

Comment: There is no animation or anything on the site you showed us... the footer is just at the bottom of the page.

Comment: hi, 
notice that when scrolling near to the bottom, the footer start to go up
and when scrolling up back, it closed down. go easy when u get there
if it's not jquery needed i will be more than glad.
Im new at programing, so..consider it...

Comment: I explored the page and i can tell you there's no animation. It is just an optical illusion because everything in in fixed position. Here, I made you an example : http://jsfiddle.net/vx31w7ay/

Comment: I can see an understand it now. thank u ( :
will use it in another case, got the solution that I wanted from Tambo in the answer 2

Answer (score 0):

you can  add/remove a given class

```
var footer = document.querySelector("#footer");
window.onscroll = function(event) {
    ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) ? footer.classList.add("visible") : footer.classList.remove("visible")
};
```

And here is your css

```
#footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow:  hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height .3s ease
}
#footer.visible{
  height: 100px;/*what ever you want*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggest there is no animation on the link you provide, but based on the link question is just simple as this:

```js
var isShowing = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()) {
        $('#footer').slideToggle();
        isShowing = true;
    } else if (isShowing === true && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() <= $(document).height() * 0.9) {
        $('#footer').slideToggle();
        isShowing = false;
    }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 1000px;
}
#footer {
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background:black;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonTest">try me</button>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: from some reason the code doesn't work for me.
anyway, got the answer from Tambo in answer 2

thank u for answering, appreciate it a lot ( :